# Why is awk performing well in efficiency

Tags: performance, awk, gawk

I found that gawk is implemented in C, and I used to write a C program to process txt file, it cost lots of time in I/O part, and maybe there is some other problems in my C program.

The program is to filter the ip address from a file, and format of each line is

```
T   218.241.107.98  117.44.215.39   7   2719    1378472723  N   0   0   0   G   0   I           218.241.107.97,0.130,1  218.241.98.45,0.265,1   192.168.1.253,0.181,1   159.226.253.77,0.218,1  159.226.253.46,4.367,1  219.142.17.37,1.062,1   118.84.3.5,2.976,1  202.97.34.134,29.026,1
```

After process, the format of each line should like this

```
218.241.107.98  117.44.215.39   218.241.107.97  218.241.98.45   192.168.1.253   159.226.253.77  159.226.253.46  219.142.17.37   118.84.3.5  202.97.34.134
```

I wrote the awk as follow

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS = "[, \t]"
}
{
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
    {
    if ($1 == "#")
        continue
    if ($i ~ /((([0-9]{1,2})|(1[0-9]{2,2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))\.){3}(([0-9]{1,2})|(1[0-9]{2,2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))/)
        printf $i"\t"
    if (i == NF)
        printf "\n"
    }
}
```

C program is too large to put upon here, i just describe its outline:

i use open()(fcntl.h) to open the origin file and redirect the standard input on that, so i use input func like scanf() or getchar() to read the file to a line buf(i process a line each time). After that, i use string function such as strchr(), to get the infomation i want, then put the to output file

for this case, the c program is much slower than awk, why?

and in general, how does awk implement in efficiency, why it is so efficient?

Any guys have some idea about that, maybe it is better to take some example.

PS: i download the source code of gawk, but it is difficult for me to read. Is there some suggestions?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: How can we tell without seeing the C and Awk code?

Comment: now i show the case @larsmans

Comment: I can still only guess, but be aware that Awk and Gawk use some pretty smart regular expression/finite automaton implementations. Awk is originally from Bell Labs, where Aho, Thompson and other automata gurus worked at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask the question in the comp.lang.awk newsgroup where it will be read by and responded to by all of the awk experts and providers, including the guys who wrote and support gawk.

Comment: @simon_xia, if you're unfamiliar with usenet, here's a link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.lang.awk

Comment: i just google it and found that group. Thanks anyway